# 5.2 Out of the box authentication customization

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel framework and I used the laravel-5.2 out of the box user authentication feature for creating a user authentication system. It is working fine. But when I want my home page to be displayed not the login page as the root. That is I want to access the login via the home page not the login page first. How can I customize my routes.

Comment: Please share the code of your `route.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that your home page route is not protected by the `auth` middleware. The default auth scaffolding provided by Laravel generates the following "home" route:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Inside the `HomeController`, in the constructor, is the following statement:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

This means that any route handled by this controller is subject to the `auth` middleware: if you're not logged in, you'll be redirected to the login page. So, if you don't want your "home" route to be protected by `auth`, you need to either remove the `auth` middleware from the `HomeController`, or create a new controller to handle your "home" route, one which does not use the `auth` middleware.